# How to reference submitted Salesforce ID with webform mapping?

Tags: webforms

The Drupal Salesforce Suite and webform documentation state:

> The ID of created/updated records are stored with the submission, and can be used in subsequent record updates in the same submission

Source: https://www.drupal.org/project/salesforce_webforms

Sadly I just don’t know how to reference it in the mapping. I first log a Case for the submission and in my second mapping I am trying things like:

```
[submissions:value:case]
[submissions:value:case:Id]
```

But it’s just trial and error, mostly error - got to be documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was using the incorrect case, it is simply:

```
[submissions:salesforce:MAPPINGNAME]
```

where MAPPINGNAME is case sensitive.  Everything you need is here:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2298943